# imacros to click on new google plus share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus, imacros

Google plus has updated their version. In new version there is a problem with clicking on share button.
Imacro clicks on the button but it just shows clicked but wont load.

[image]

I am using the following code.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=CONTENT ATTR=CLASS:N9wOvf
```

See the 2nd screenshot:
[image]

Its just clicked but wont load.
Please help me to sort out the problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using EVENT command. Record with Experimental recording and place some waiting times.

Comment: I am not familiar with EVENT command, can you please give me a EVENT command for ATTR=CLASS:N9wOvf?